# Why Java type erasure works only for instance methods?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

```
class Genero<T> {
    static List<String> getThat() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    List<String> getThis() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
public class Generic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Genero g = new Genero();
        for (String s : g.getThis()) {} //compile error: requiered String, found Object

        for (String s : Genero.getThat()) {} //compiles fine
}
}
```

Whats up?
According to type erasure idea I shouldn't be able to use generic method getThis/getThat in BOTH cases. But I can use it for static method. Why?